# Azure B2c authentication in android

Tags: android, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am searching for a sample of how azure b2c authentication is integrated into Android. Basically, I need to enable login/signup. There are so many examples but the one I am expecting. Please help me with this.

I tried your sample given in Git repo. And getting
Error occurred during authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can find the simplest and recommended example for Android with Azure ad B2c [here](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android)

AppAuth for Android is a client SDK for communicating with OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect providers. It strives to directly map the requests and responses of those specifications, while following the idiomatic style of the implementation language. In addition to mapping the raw protocol flows, convenience methods are available to assist with common tasks like performing an action with fresh tokens.

The library follows the best practices set out in OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps including using Custom Tabs for the auth request. For this reason, WebView is explicitly not supported due to usability and security reasons.

The library also supports the PKCE extension to OAuth which was created to secure authorization codes in public clients when custom URI scheme redirects are used. The library is friendly to other extensions (standard or otherwise) with the ability to handle additional parameters in all protocol requests and responses.

This sample demonstrates how to use Azure AD B2C using a 3rd party library called AppAuth. It has only been tested for compatibility in basic scenarios with Azure AD B2C. Issues and feature requests should be directed to the library's open-source project.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So you would like to authenticate your android application using azure B2C.

To do that follow the below steps:

**Register Your Application:**

1. Create your application on `azure portal` as `Native Client`
2. For Android make sure select `Allow implicit flow` to `Yes`

See the screen shot below:

[image]

You could also check application registration process [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications#register-a-web-application)

**Configure Your Application Id and Application Secret:**

Once you have created your application now you have to configure

1. Published scopes:

See the screen shot:

[image]

2. Keys:

Generate your application `Secret` Clicking on `Key` side menu. Then click on `Generate key` and click `Save`. See the below screen shot

[image]

**Android Application configuration:**

Download this [`Android Application`](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) and configure Your `Application Id` which is `CLIENT_ID` and `REDIRECT_URI` copy both from your azure portal registered application.

Now follow the [instruction](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) to sign in your application.